# Subversion Can't read length line in file

Tags: svn, fsfs

When I commit I had no error. Now I tried to check out and I got this error

Can't read length line in file 'c:\svn\db\revs\0\14'

I have tried older revision it doesn't work either. Does it mean I lost everything in subversion ?

Comment: I fail to see how this is programming-related.

Comment: @unwind From [help-->What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: Great, this issue still occurs 3 years later.  Luckily not on a large commercial codebase and don't have much too much lost history to worry about, so I'm tempted to start over with git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is simple fix I found without administering the SVN repository.

1. the error was produced by a specific file that I had to commit.
2. I committed all other changed files Ok
3. I copied the local file to the desktop as a backup
4. SVN->Delete file
5. commit the folder. It was successful
6. added the file from the desktop in the local folder
7. svn -> add,  svn->commit

problem fixed. I think this way you loose the previous versions of the file from the repository but this was not a problem for me.

Hope this info can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can run

```
svnadmin verify /var/svn/repo
```

to check your repository.

In case you use Berkeley db (you shouldn't),

```
svnadmin recover /var/svn/repo
```

may help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Berkeley database have been corrupted, you should use `FSFS` backend next time. For now see [Berkeley DB Recovery](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.recovery).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be SVN bug or some H/W failure. I would start looking for a backup.
If you don't have one - you can commit your local working copy in new repository.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like db have been corrupted for one of your revision.

So, at first you can update to previous revision and change last revision in db:

```
svn update -r99
vi /var/svn/site/db/current
[change number to "99"]
```

Than you must find out what directory is broken and replace it in repository.
[corrupted] - name of your corrupted directory.

```
cd /var/www/site/
svn delete --keep-local [corrupted]
svn ci [corrupted] -m "Remove corrupted directory from repository"
rm -rf `find /[corrupted] -name .svn`
svn add [corrupted]
svn ci [corrupted] -m "Add fixed directory"
```